# Layout not being applied on page load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have a different layout I want to be applied to my blogs. So in the blog controller I put

```
layout: 'blog'
```

at the top of my blogs controller above the index action.

When I physically refresh the page, the blog layout is applied. But if I link to the blog_path from the homepage, the layout does not get applied, it still uses the same layout as the homepage. Again, when I manually refresh the page it applies the layout. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have turbolinks enabled? If so, this may be your problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Turbolinks**

The problem will be `Turbolinks`

Turbolinks is a javascript library which works by taking your links, checking to see whether the overall "page" will change, and if not, just pulling the `<body>` tag rom the requested resource. Although a pain, it's designed for efficiency:

> Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.
>   Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS
>   between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and
>   replaces only the body and the title in the head. Think CGI vs
>   persistent process.

--

The main issue for Turbolinks is that it will often just reload the `<body>` tag of your page, which is the issue you're seeing here.

In most use cases, this will break the JS / CSS present on the page; however, for you it seems that the issue is with being able to load the `layout` of your other actions

---

**Fix**

The fix for this is more of a test (I've never used Turbolinks with `layout` specific issues before)

I would recommend doing this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//require turbolinks -> REMOVE THIS LINE

#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<head>
  ...
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %> #-> remove turbolinks references
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> #-> remove turbolinks references
</head>
```

This will basically remove any references to Turbolinks, allowing you to test to see if this is indeed the problem. I know it is, because having the layout applied on page refresh is the hallmark sign of a Turbolinks issue (Turbolinks cannot work if you refresh the page); it's just a question of how to work with it

Answer (score 0):

In the layout folder if you define blog.html.erb it will load it in BlogController.

Answer (score 0):

you must have a `app/views/layout/blog.html.erb` layout file.